# How would one add force to a rigidbody from a relative mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game I am creating in Unity. It has a table with 30 cubes on it. I want a user to be able to shuffle the cubes on the table using their mouse/touch.

I am currently using a ray to get the initial table/cube hit point then accessing the rigidbody component on the cube to apply a force using AddForceAtPosition, happening in an OnMouseDrag. I am also pulling out my hair trying to figure out how to apply force in the direction from the mouse's last position to the hit point on the rigidbody of the cube.

Can someone please help me? An example would be great. I would share my code but I am a spaghetti code monster and fear criticism... Thanks much!

Comment: Instead of adding a force, maybe it would be easier to modify position directly on each frame while OnMouseDrag

Comment: @AlexLarionov That is true, but I want to account for a point on the table to apply the right force and not just select the cubes to move. If I'm understanding you right... Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, is something like this you want to achieve? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Zli2CJGAtU&feature=youtu.be

If so, first you have to add your cubes and table to a new layermask, this step is only necessary if you don't want your ray to hit other colliders that might mess with your result.

After this you should add a tag to all the cubes you want to aplly the force, in my case I added a new tag called "Cubes".

You can search on youtube this if you don't know how to do it, there are plenty of tutorials to help you.

After that you create a new script and attach to the camera. Here is my script:

```
public class CameraForceMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector3 lastPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lastPosition = new Vector3();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 200f, layerMask))
            {
                if (hit.transform.CompareTag("Cubes"))
                {
                    Rigidbody rb = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                    Vector3 force = (hit.point - lastPosition).normalized * 55f;

                    rb.AddForceAtPosition(force, hit.point);

                }

                lastPosition = hit.point;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Just want to say that there are a lot of ways to achieve the same thing, this is the way I decided to do, but there are probably other (maybe even better) ways of doing this.

Explaining the code:

The first thing is a `public LayerMask` that before you play the game you will have to select your camera in your scene and look for the script on the editor in the right side and select witch layerMask you added to your cubes and table.

If you don't know how raycast works, here is the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html but you can also search on youtube.

The important thing here is the new vector being created to define the direction of the force.

First we declare a global variable called LastPosition, and for every frame that we are clicking, we will check for a collision, and if this collision happens, we will then create a new vector going out of the last position the mouse was to the position the mouse is now `Vector3 force = (hit.point - lastPosition)`, than we normalize it because we only care about the direction and multiply it by the amount of force we want, you can make it as a nice variable but I just put it there directly.

Then, after you've applied the force to the position the ray hit the object, you have to define that this is now your last position, since you are going to the next frame. Remember to put it outside of the Tag check, because this is checking if the object we collided with is the cube we want to apply the force or if it is the table. If we add this line `lastPosition = hit.point;` inside of this check it will only assign a new lastPosition value when we hit the cube, and would lead to bugs.

I'm not saying my answer is perfect, I can think of a few bugs that can happen, when you click outside the table for example, but is a good start, and I think you can fix the rest.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a well put together solution with a video example that is similar to what I want to achieve! I honestly thought I didn't explain myself well enough. Thanks again mate!